# How to test interactive python script with multiple `input` functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I know how to test python functions with a single `input` function, but I can't seem to figure out how to test python functions with multiple `input` functions in it.

Please see the below minimal example code `test.py` below:

```
import pytest
import mock
import builtins


def unsubscribe():
    if input("are you unsubscribing? [y/n]") == "n":
        return "we are glad to have you back"
    else:
        if input("would you like a 20%% off discount code? [y/n]") == "y":
            return "your discount code is SAVE20, and we are glad you have you back"
        else:
            return "we are sad to see you go"


def test_unsubscribe():
    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda _: 'n'):
        assert unsubscribe() == "we are glad to have you back"
    with mock.patch.object(builtins, 'input', lambda _: 'y'):
        assert unsubscribe() == "your discount code is SAVE20, and we are glad you have you back"
    # what to put here to test the below
    #    assert unsubscribe() == "we are sad to see you go"
```

With the current approach, the mock patch replaces every single `input` function as all `n` or all `y`, which causes the control flow of first input `y` and second input `n` unreachable. What is the right way to unit test a python function with multiple `input` functions in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `side_effect` for this. [Side_effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) takes a list as input and provides you the result in the order of elements.

Assuming you have the test and source code in separate directories

```
@patch('sample.input')
def test_options(mock_input):
   mock_input.side_effect = ['y', 'y']
   result = unsubscribe()
   assert result == "your discount code is SAVE20, and we are glad you have you back"
```

You can take this to the next step by defining the exact output you want for your use case, instead of arbitrarily passing yes and no values

```
@patch('sample.input')
def test_options(mock_input):

   def input_side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
       m = {
           'are you unsubscribing? [y/n]': 'y',
           'would you like a 20%% off discount code? [y/n]': 'y',
       }.get(args[0])
       if m:
           return m
       pytest.fail('This question is not expected')

   mock_input.side_effect = input_side_effect
   result = unsubscribe()
   assert result == "your discount code is SAVE20, and we are glad you have you back"
```

Comment: When I run `pytest test.py` I am getting `NameError: name 'patch' is not defined` with your code, and if I remove the line `@patch('sample.input')`, I am getting  `fixture 'mock_input' not found`, any ideas?

Comment: NVM after `from unittest.mock import patch` it runs, thanks!